# Populating a jsp drop-down menu with the values present in database

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

How to populate a drop-down menu in JSP with the values present in the database (following MVC architecture) ?
Tried doing this 
Inside 
EmployeeDAO.java

```
private List<EmployeeVO> empIDList;

    public List<EmployeeVO> getStateList(){
        empIDList=new ArrayList<EmployeeVO>();
        Connection con=DBUtil.getConnection();



        try {
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select Emp_id from Employee order by Emp_id ASC");
            while(rs.next()){
                String emID=rs.getString("Emp_id");
                int empID=Integer.parseInt(emID);
                EmployeeVO s=new EmployeeVO();
                s.setEmp_id(empID); 
                empIDList.add(s);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return empIDList;
    }
```

Inside 
EmployeeVO.java

```
private int Emp_id;
    private String Emp_pwd;
    private String Emp_fname;
    private String Emp_mname;
    private String Emp_lname;
    private String Emp_dob;
    private String Emp_doj;
    private String Emp_status;
    public int getEmp_id() {
        return Emp_id;
    }
    public void setEmp_id(int emp_id) {
        Emp_id = emp_id;
    }
```

Inside 
Employee.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<jsp:useBean id="emplID" scope="session" class="com.model.EmployeeVO" />

<th>Employee ID</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="EID" id="eid" /> 
                    <select
                        id="testlist">
                            <c:forEach var="item" items="${emplID.items}">
                                <option>${item}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                    </select> 
                    </td>
```

The source code for the jsp was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901222/populate-jsp-dropdown-with-database-info) page

Comment: try refering this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850279/display-selected-value-of-the-drop-down-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this `Vector` or `arraylist` method ..

### jsp part (vector)

```
<%
  Vector vFRUIT_CODE    = new Vector();
  Vector vFRUIT_DESCP   = new Vector();

  String SQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_TEST";
  DB_TEST.makeConnection();
  DB_TEST.executeQuery(SQL);
  while(DB_TEST.getNextQuery())
  {
           String sCODE    = DB_TEST.getColumnString("FRUIT_CODE");
           String sDESCP   = DB_TEST.getColumnString("FRUIT_DESCP");

          vFRUIT_CODE.addElement(sCODE);
          vFRUIT_DESCP.addElement(sDESCP);
  }
  DB_TEST.takeDown();
%>
```

### html  part

```
<select name="FRUIT">
<option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
<%
    for (int i=0;i<vFRUIT_CODE.size();i++) {
          String sCODE = (String) vFRUIT_CODE.elementAt(i);
          String sDESCP = (String) vFRUIT_DESCP.elementAt(i);
 %>      
<option value="<%=sCODE %>" ><%= sDESCP %></option>
<%}%>  
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Since using scriptlets in JSP will have performance impacts. How can we implement this using MVC?